# XSLT - add new element as parent element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like follows,

```
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Test table head col 1</th>
                    <th><span>Test table head col 2</span></th>
                    <th><span>Test table head col 3</span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
                    <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
                    <td>Row 1 Column 3</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
                    <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
                    <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
                    <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
                    <td>Row 3 Column 4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

using XSLT I have to get the following output from above xml,

```
<table>       
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry namest="1">
                            <p type="Table head">Test table head col 1</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="2">
                            <p type="Table head">Test table head col 2</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="3">
                            <p type="Table head">Test table head col 3</p>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry namest="1" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 1 Column 1</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="2" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 1 Column 2</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="3" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 1 Column 3</p>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry namest="1" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 2 Column 1</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="2" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 2 Column 2</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="3" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 2 Column 3</p>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry namest="1" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 3 Column 1</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="2" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 3 Column 2</p>
                        </entry>
                        <entry namest="3" align="left">
                            <p type="Table text">Row 3 Column 4</p>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>                
        </table>
```

to get that output I've written following xsl,

```
<xsl:template match="tbody/tr[1]">
        <thead>
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="th">
                    <entry namest="{position()}">
                        <p type="Table head"><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
                    </entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </thead>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tbody/tr[not(position()=1)]">
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="td">
                    <entry namest="{position()}" align="left">
                        <p type="Table text"><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
                    </entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>
```

But it adds `<tbody>` to every `<tr>` nodes. How can I modify my code to add only one `<tbody>` element to cover `<tr>` elements from second element to final element as my expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to take is to match the `tbody` element, and then do specific processing to create a `thead` element for the first row, and then only copy the remaining rows to the `tbody`

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="tbody">
        <thead>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[1]" />
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[position() > 1]" />
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you wanted to cope with a situation where there was already a `thead`, or perhaps no `tbody` at all, you could match on the `table` element instead. Try this XSLT too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="(.//tr)[1]" />
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="(.//tr)[position() > 1]" />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way :

```
<xsl:template match="tbody/tr[position()=2]">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody/tr[position()&gt;1]">
    <row>
        <xsl:for-each select="td">
            <entry namest="{position()}" align="left">
                <p type="Table text"><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
            </entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Yz)</kbd>**

The first template adds `tbody` parent element on processing each of the 2nd `tr`, and the last template adds `row` element inside the formerly added `tbody` for each `tr` at position index greater than 1.